# Calculate overall status if progress and daysLeft percent are known

Tags: algorithm, progress, status, calculation

If the `progress` and `daysLeft` percent of my goal are known, how can I determine overall status of goal (assuming that defined statuses are `off-track`, `at-risk`, `on-track` and `completed`).

For boundary case:

- if progress is `100%` no matter what is daysLeft percent, I know that my goal status
  is `completed`
- if daysLeft percent is `0%` and progress is less than `100%`, I know that my goal is `off-track`

I need logic that will take into account progress and days left to determine one of mentioned statuses during goal duration.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is a matter of opinion, but you could do something like this:

```
if progress == 100%: status = completed; return;

if progress >= 100% - daysLeft: status = on-track; return;

if daysLeft > 0: status = at-risk; return;

status = off-track;
```

That way your two conditions are satisfied, and the status is on-track when there are more days left than the allocated amount of time for that work and at-risk when there is not.

(You can change the return statements to if-else's, if you want.)

Does this work for you?